# Regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

How i can write a regular expression for validate a "right Human Name":

My definition of human name (in this case):
I need validate Hispanic names: Something like Maria, John, jon, Andrés will be valid, but something like 'NNNNNatalia' doesn't

I mean this is valid:

- Diego
- Diego A.
- Diego A.   Sanabria

This is not valid:

- Diego 3
- Diiiiiiiego
- #$%ego

Comment: Diiiiiiiego sounds like a good name

Comment: This is poorly suited to regex solutions.  You're looking for a validation algorithm, not a regular expression.

Comment: What *exactly* is your definition of a valid human name?

Comment: Are you sure you know the rules? What about [Khoisan languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khoisan_languages) which are written with ! to mean the click sound?

Comment: You'll need a strict definition of what's valid and what isn't. Just for example, would you consider "Deigo Sanabria 3rd" valid? Many people would.

Comment: I think if you want a generic solution that would be used to validate a 'correct' human name, regular expressions is not what you want to use. What if someone was called Diiego?

Comment: the problem for the regexp is something like 'Diiiiego'. But i think is posible do this with a regexp

Comment: There are no rules for what makes a "valid" human name. I could call my son "fffff" (pronounced "Dave") if I wanted.

Comment: @diegueus9, you are either ignoring the questions other people ask what your definition of "valid" is, or are unsure about it yourself. It it's the latter, you shouldn't ask the question but need to figure that out first. If you *do* have a definition, please post it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure someone else has a better expression, but `([A-Za-z.]+) ?([A-Z]\.?)? ?([A-Za-z]+)` will match your input text. It will also match *lots* of other things.

It won't match Mário or François or 優恵. It won't match names containing more than 3 words, or hyphenated last names, etc. It won't match "Bobby Tables" ...

Assuming you're working with names written in latin characters, you may be able to match words against a list of first names. When you find a first name (assuming that first names come first in your data), then inspect the next couple of words to see if they could also be names.

It's generally better to let humans enter their own names.

Comment: this could work for me, but doesn't validate non-ascii letters, you know how i can do that?

Comment: You need to add all of the accented characters in the character class. For Spanish, it should be something like `([A-Za-záéíóúñ]+)`.

Comment: @diegueus9 This WILL NOT work for you...you are quickly approaching a Clbuttic error and will be mocked mercilessly by your team if you even consider implementing it. Read more closely what Seth is saying...he is saying, 'Don't Use This'. His regex will even match an item in your own invalid list....you are currently in the part of the map that says 'Here There Be Monsters'.

Comment: +1 Keng! I didn't know 'clbuttic' was a word. I would have *loved* to have known that word about 2 years ago when I was fixing a broken profanity filter in some message board software.

Answer (score 6):

This is way beyond the scope of regular expressions. You'll need a Dictionary of names, and possibly an algorithm to check for things which aren't in your dictionary but are names (do some research into [Markov Chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) for a start). You'll then need some [Natural Language Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) [algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) to parse the [syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax) for valid names.

In short: Take a degree in Computer Science, and this might be a potential Dissertation project.